# removing item in kendo-multiselect removes all items

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have kendo-multislect with following configuration

```
<kendo-multiselect
              formControlName="selectedLanguages"
              #languagesList
              (valueChange)="onSelectedLanguageChange($event)"
              [autoClose]="false"
              textField="Language"
              valueField="UseChannelLanguage"
              [data]="availableLanguages">
</kendo-multiselect>
```

For now I have to create array of items like this... It comes from backend in string[], and I have to have array of object like this [{Language: english, UseChannelLanguage: false}, etc... etc...]

```
  private _languages: string[];
  @Input()
  public get languages(): string[] {
    return this._languages;
  }
  public set languages(value: string[]) {
    if (value) {
      this._languages = value;

      this.availableLanguages = value.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        return [...prev, { Language: curr, UseChannelLanguage: false }];
      }, [] as PhotoSelectorLanguageFeatureLanguage[]);
    }
  }
```

And it works just fine, but problem occurs, when Im removing one item in multi-select input, it removes everything and leaves selectedLanguages control as empty  array []

I have never faced this problem before.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you look into what `onSelectedLanguageChange($event)` does?

Comment: it does nothing. It is empty

Comment: Even If I reduce it to this   <kendo-multiselect textField="Language" valueField="UseChannelLanguage" [data]="availableLanguages"> it still happens... When I set [data] input to simple array of strings it works as supposed to work

Comment: Ok I know what the issue is. I just cannot set valueField property to boolean - it should be number as in kendo docs... but this is unfortunate to me, because I would like to set languages  with boolean property using custom tag template...

Comment: Luckilly I can have multiple properties in single object of kendo-multiselect, so perhaps I can handle the rest !

Answer (score 0):

valueField should be set as number only, additional properties can be set e.g like this : {Language: 'bs-Latn-BA', UseChannelLanguage: true, Value: 5}